# Why Codeigniter is showing error "Missing argument 1 for tc_calendar::tc_calendar()"

Tags: codeigniter, calendar, datepicker

I have been trying to use tc_calender in my codeigniter for data picking.

I have stored the tc_calender.php & calendar_form.php in libraries folder and in autoload.php mentioned as:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','tc_calendar');
```

Also included the following are working properly:

```
<?php define('TLOGICURL', base_url()); ?>
<script src="<?php echo TLOGICURL;?>assets/js/calendar.js"></script>
<link href="<?php echo TLOGICURL;?>assets/css/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But it is showing following errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Missing argument 1 for tc_calendar::tc_calendar(), called in D:\xampp\htdocs\tlogic\system\core\Loader.php on line 1099 and defined
Filename: libraries/tc_calendar.php
Line Number: 101

and

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: objname
Filename: libraries/tc_calendar.php
Line Number: 102
```

Comment: we can not debug the issue without seeing the code.. need tc_calendar.php file could u please copy the code and paste in your topic?

Answer (score 0):

`tc_calendar::tc_calendar()` is the constructor for the `tc_calendar` class. You can't pass constructor arguments in autoload, and using `$this->load->library()` only allows a single argument that must be an array.

One way to make this work is to create a subclass of tc_calendar and load that instead.

```
<?php
include_once 'tc_calendar.php';
class my_calendar extends tc_calendar {
  public function __construct(array $config = array()) {
    $arg = array_key_exists('argname', $config) ? $config['argname'] : DEFAULT;
    base::tc_calendar($arg);
  }
}
```

Then you can either autoload, or load manually with an additional argument like this:

```
$this->load->library('my_calendar', array('argument'));
```

You should replace `'argname'` and `DEFAULT` with something that makes sense, and possibly add more arguments if the tc_calendar constructor uses them.